# How to properly visualize and download an image from a server post response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, post

I'm using a form to send a picture to a server that performs some transformation on it, and returns the new resulted picture.

So far, I'm using the info from this link without the php part as I'm already calling a server somewhere else. Also, I copied and used the open code, didn't download the complete solution using the paid option provided:

https://www.formget.com/ajax-image-upload-php/

And in the javascript I changed the $("#message") line for this:

```
$("#message").html(data); ==> 
$('#message').html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + data + '" />');
```

With that, I'm able to upload the picture and get a response but I can't figure out how to proper visualize it or download it as a picture (I need both of this options working)

You can see what I'm getting as a result:

Result after retrieving response
[image]

The interesting part is that if I use firefox dev. ed. and check the log on the console, I can see the response as Raw Data and if I click in "load more", the resulted picture is displayed as I'm expected to see it

Raw Data

[image]

Resulted image (I had to cover it and the server url)

[image]

Does anyone have any idea about how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

This is how my POST call code looks like:

```
   $(document).ready(function (e) {
      $("#uploadimage").on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#message").empty();
        $('#loading').show();
        $.ajax({
          url: "https://API_Im_calling.com",
          type: "POST",             
          data: new FormData(this),
          contentType: false,
          responseType: 'image/png', //I also tried 'binary' and 'blob' with similar results
          cache: false,             
          processData:false,        
          success: function(data)   
          {
            $('#loading').hide();

            //Here the options I tried
            //1. For the 'blob' trial didn't know how to display the blob as an image on the HTML
            //var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/png'});
            //console.log(blob);

            //2. This is what I'm using in combination with a HTML tag to try to display the picture
            $('#message').html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + data + '" />');
      }
    });
  }));
```

**EDIT 2**

The API works as a tried calling it using Python and it returns and displays the picture properly.

Comment: Did you double check your base64 string is correct? You can try using this to check https://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: Yes, I did. It doesn't work with the characters displayed in the html. It does work with the raw data returned by the server but that was already clear, since I could see the returned image using FIrefox dev console.

Comment: I discovered something else: when using the site recommended by @AndrewLohr, if I paste the raw data from the Firefox console into that site and look into its source code, I can see the same character format that what it's displayed in my site as HTML, still clueless about how to solve this

Comment: Is it one of the new picture formats?

Comment: @F__ Did you try decoding in a different charset than UTF-8?